# Accessing model data from a view with backbone.js

Tags: json, backbone.js, view, models

I have the following code but am struggling to get my view to render the template instead of my model. It all works fine if I render the handlebars template through my model but would like to separate my code into the view.

```
var DataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        $.getJSON('js/data.json',function(data){
            $('.one-wrapper').append(Handlebars.compile($('#one-template').html())(data));
            $('.one-asset-loader').fadeOut('slow');
        });
    },

    defaults : function () {

    },

});

var StructureView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    initialize: function () {
    }
});

var structureView = new StructureView({model: new DataModel()});
```

Comment: Your model shouldn't really be doing any direct DOM manipulation. You should have a view take care of that stuff prompted by a change in the state of your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the model inside the view using `this.model`.

Your code should look something like:

```
var StructureView = Backbone.View.extend ({
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.render();
        this.model.on('change',this.render);
    },
    render: function() {
        $('.one-wrapper').empty().append(Handlebars.compile($('#one-template').html())( this.model.toJSON() ));
    }
});
```

This will work assuming your model actually contains the data. To do this you need to use the `model.url` and `model.fetch()` (not `$.getJSON`)